# How To invoke method in SKScene from a listener in another class in Swift?

Tags: swift, delegates, admob, skscene

I have a separate class that handle my `adMob` code.
In this class I have all the listeners methods such as:

```
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {...}
```

In my SKScene I present the `RewardedAds` and I need to have also a method that will get called when the `rewardBasedVideoAd` method is called.

I've tried to implement the `delegate` way like this:
in the `AdsManager` class:

```
protocol Ads_Rewarded_SupportDelegate: class{
func rewardedFinishSuccessfuly()
func rewardedAdClosed()}
```

And in the `Ads_Rewarded_Support` I added:

```
weak var delegate: Ads_Rewarded_SupportDelegate?
```

In the

```
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
 delegate?.rewardedFinishSuccessfuly()}
```

In my SKScene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, Ads_Rewarded_SupportDelegate { 
private let rewardedAd = Ads_Rewarded_Support()
rewardedAd.delegate = self
```

And eventually:

```
func rewardedFinishSuccessfuly() {
   print("rewarded Finish Successfuly")
}
```

But still I clould'nt get to invoke this `rewardedFinishSuccessfuly` method.
How can I invoke my method in `SKScene` when the `rewardBasedVideoAd` is called?

If it helps here is link for the project:
[project on Github](https://github.com/EranKT/UfoShoot)

Edit:
When I call from my `GameScene` manually method that should activate the delegated method, it works. So my problem is in the `pointer`. It is not keeping alive the instance, so when `didRewardUserWith` is called, my `GameScene` is not the delegate anymore.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your project?

Comment: Thanks @damiancesar Here is the link to the project: [link](https://github.com/EranKT/UfoShoot)

Comment: I've tried to use the GameViewController as a listener, but still the delegate methods are not being called. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work!
The problem was that my pointer to the `AdsSupport` class was not alive.
I added:
 `return Ads_Rewarded_Support.rewardedAdsPointer!` and call the ads:

```
rewardedAd = Ads_Rewarded_Support().presentRewardAdFor(scene: self)
```

Then I set the delegate to self.
Thank you for doing your best to help me on this head breaking case.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `Ads_Rewarded_SupportDelegate` is good.

The issue you're having is because the [reward based video ad fails to load](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/api/reference/Protocols/GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate#/c:objc(pl)GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate(im)rewardBasedVideoAd:didFailToLoadWithError:).

Therefore, the following don't get called:

```
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward)
func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd)
```

Checking your console log, you'll see:

```
You are currently using version 7.25.0 of the SDK. 
Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version 
to get the latest features and bug fixes.

Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show."
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show.,
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}
```

I'd do as recommended here. Hopefully that resolves the issue you're having!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to update. though I'm not sure if it will help because even when reward ad do show, and the `print("USER RECEIVED REWARD")` is shown in the console log, still it is not invoking the delegate method. Is it possible to be related to the fact that I call the `preloadRewardAds` from the  gameViewController and not the GameScene?

Comment: Hi @damiancesar, like I thought, I updated the `adMob SDK, fixed errors, and still: I got reward ad, got in the console log USER RECEIVED REWARD and REWARD - AD CLOSED, and still non of the delegate methods were not called. any other idea?